# Debian: plymouth splash screen does not change

Tags: debian, bootsplash, plymouth

on my Debian box, I have installed Plymouth for a splash screen. I have tried updating the theme but everytime I use the commands:

`/usr/sbin/plymouth-set-default-theme myTHEME`

and then try to update it with: `update-initramfs -u`
and add the word `splash` to the `/etc/default/grub` file
and update the grub by: `update-grub`

the theme i get are simple blue and white bars at the bottom of the screen and the word `Debian` appears. I've tried changing to the default installed themes and still i have the same theme. Is there something I'm not doing to update it properly?

Comment: Simple? Is it text mode? Make sure you have a drm driver at boot time.

Comment: Simple - there's nothing fancy about the blue progress bar. Text Mode- how do I check for that? DRM driver at Boot Time- I guess I can look online for how to check but do you know how?

Comment: did you update initramfs with sudo first?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue getting the boot splash to change on CentOS 6. After creating a custom theme and initiating the initramfs rebuild, upon reboot the theme had not changed. This was fixed by specifying the VGA mode in the grub configuration file by adding

`vga=<code>`

to the boot line, where (in my case) `<code>` was `791` for a 16bit 1024x768. You may need to play around with the codes for your platform to get it to work.